# how to get checkbox value in websql

Tags: html, sqlite, local-storage, web-sql

I have made an offline database application that can store three form field values. How can i store check box vales. i have tried this...

```
 db.transaction(function(tx) {
  tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test1(id integer primary key autoincrement, field1 , field2, field3,chkbx)');
});

 var inputchkbx=document.getElementById("chkbx").value;

  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test1(field1,field2,field3,chkbx) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',[inputField1,inputField2,inputField3,inputchkbx],
```

Butthis not doing any good

Answer (score 0):

Websql has nothing to do with what you have on UI. all that matters is that you should have correct insert statement with valid values. So I would say first pass some hard coded values in insert to verify if your code is correct and then log/alert your check box value to ensure that it is indeed what you think it is. I see missing closing part in your insert statement assuming it is just a copy paste error.  Test your page in Chrome, open chrome debugger via F12 and execute it to see the exact error.